# WMI in Win32 Service (COM initialization error)

Tags: security, visual-c++, com, wmi, access-denied

I work on some WMI client and it works fine as console standalone application. But when I try to wrap it as Win32 Service it fails on:

```
HRESULT hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UnsecuredApartment, 0, 
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IUnsecuredApartment, 
    (void**)&unsecuredApartment);
```

*CoCreateInstance* fails with error **0x80070005** (ACCESS DENIED);

I call it from "main" thread before OnStart callback. COM already initialized with flag **COINIT_MULTITHREADED**; OS is Windows 7;

Help me please how to pass this problem?

Comment: It seems the service identity has not enough rights for this call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, like Simon said service needs access rights; In services.msc -> Service Name -> Properties -> Log on -> need set right domain user and password; It is works for me;